# Is it possible to send blog posts via email to subscribers?

Tags: plugins, posts, email, blog, html-email

Would like to be able to send the blog post in an email mail to my subscribers, this would be great if it can be achieved through a plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many options.  Subscribe2 is very popular, although I've never been a fan. http://subscribe2.wordpress.com/

MailChimp and FeedBurner both offer RSS to Email delivery which can be used for this as well.

JetPack includes a subscribe to new posts function as well: http://jetpack.me/2011/11/29/how-to-use-email-subscriptions-in-jetpack-1-2/

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to send an email to subscribers whenever a new Blog post is published? If this, you can use [Subscribe2](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/subscribe2/) plugin.

Comment: But it's not sending an email, do I need to do any setting to make that happen .?